# React change selected item index of array using order number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am new developer at Reactjs. I have a question. It's maybe simple but I want to learn best practice or best way about changing selected item index of array according to user order number. I mean user will give a number from Input and I will use that number for placement inside the array.

Example Object Array in My State :

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
    dragFrames:
       [{id:1,name:"test-1",zIndex:1},
       {id:2,name:"test-2",zIndex:2},
       {id:3,name:"test-3",zIndex:3}]
    })
```

User zIndex Input **"1"** to item which id is **3**

My expected new Array order is below:

```
dragFrames:
       [id:3,name:"test-3",zIndex:1},
       {id:1,name:"test-1",zIndex:2},
       {id:2,name:"test-2",zIndex:3}
       ]
```

I can change and set zIndex number of any object but I cant change array order according to input value. How can I do this? Could you help me ?

I tried this before and I faced endless loop:

```
 if (e.target.value>0) {
                nowDev.z = e.target.value
                var arrayCopy = state.dragFrames.slice()
                state.dragFrames.map((item:any,index:any)=>{
                    if (index===e.target.value) {
                        arrayCopy.push(nowDev)
                    }else{
                        arrayCopy.push(item)
                    }
                })
                setState({ dragFrames: arrayCopy})
                
            }
```

Comment: Could you provide more information? Like usage of `setState` for example

Comment: What I understand. use `map` and and updated based on your id. Then sort by id. Then save in state

Comment: I made an edit for my code check that @demkovych

Comment: I tired something  check pls @ShubhamVerma

Comment: You need to slice your array you can simply doing using spread operator.`var arrayCopy = [...state.dragFrames];
arrayCopy.dragFrames.map((item: any, index: any) => {
  if (index === e.target.value) {
    return nowDev;
  }
  return item;
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is sorting example. You need to push elements first.

```
if (e.target.value > 0) {
  const newArray = state.dragFrames.map((el, index) => index === e.target.value ? e.target.value : item);

  setState({
    dragFrames: newArray.sort((a, b) => a.zIndex.localeCompare(b.zIndex))
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to change zIndex of all elements in the array.
Algorithm for it will be following:

1. Map over the array and increment zIndex of all elements
2. for the element which is set by user, set it's zIndex to 1

Once above is done, sort by zIndex.

Code is mentioned below:

```js
df = [{id:1,name:"test-1",zIndex:1},
       {id:2,name:"test-2",zIndex:2},
       {id:3,name:"test-3",zIndex:3}];
       
const updatedDF = df.map(x => {
    if(x.id === 3) return {...x, zIndex: 1}  // replace 3 with e.target.value
    else return {...x, zIndex: x.zIndex + 1}
});

updatedDF.sort((x, y) => x.zIndex - y.zIndex)

console.log(updatedDF)
```

Comment: I am still trying something it does not correct solution.

Comment: According to what you mentioned in question, above solution seems right to me... Can you point where exactly the output is wrong